# How to define constant Pubkeys while developing with Anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

I want to define pubkeys of certain mints as constants to use throughout my Anchor program, how would I go about it?

I remember seeing some code using `declare_id` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `pubkey` macro, defined [here](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/macro.pubkey.html).

```
#[cfg(not(feature = "devnet"))]
pub mod mints {
    use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};
    pub const SOL: Pubkey = pubkey!("So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112");
    pub const USDC: Pubkey = pubkey!("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v");
}

#[cfg(feature = "devnet")]
pub mod mints {
    use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};
    pub const SOL: Pubkey = pubkey!("57z5KG1EHj5SV79xR1GVzEvkjWSJHgA7XMuPE457Rain");
    pub const USDC: Pubkey = pubkey!("Hqyx6oJbZ2LBdshEP9ApdSMoo1xKQSgBjEAAbzJhMbZY");
}
```

---

Also note that if you are using Anchor you would need to add `solana_program` into `Cargo.toml`, otherwise macro would not be exported. To use the same version Anchor uses you can add `solana_program` in this way:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.24.2"
solana-program = "*" # Will be resolved to the same version as in `anchor-lang`.
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it is to define the key as a const with type &str. To use it in your program as a Pubkey you'd only need to parse it into a Pubkey. For example:

```
const MINT: &str = "2TPExuywxs4K7J2WAE8N8FiAMTPANvNXg9AV3ds7iybv";
```

And to use in say your validator:

```
constraint = mint.key() == MINT.parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap()
```

or

```
constraint = mint.key() == Pubkey::new(MINT.as_bytes())
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the obvious way to do it as well. I am wondering if declare_id has any other benefit apart from giving a `Pubkey` directly?

Comment: You're welcome. So far as I know, declare_id only sets your program's Pubkey. Anchor says it can only be defined once so I assume that means it doesn't have any other use

Comment: `bas58` decoding is _very_ expensive and should be discouraged at runtime, especially in an on-chain program

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Per @trent.sol comment, there is an even more natural [macro](https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.11.4/solana_program/macro.pubkey.html) that can be used:

```
use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};

static ID: Pubkey = pubkey!("My11111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
```

---

**OG answer:** You can use `declare_id` for that. For example:

```
use anchor_lang::solana_program::declare_id;

mod my_mint {
    declare_id("....");
}
```

Under the hood, `declare_id` just generates a `Pubkey` with the base 58 encoded string you provide turned into a byte array.

---

Tangentially, if you are going to use a mint in your Anchor program, in all likelihood, you have to pass into the instruction. At which point, you will have access to the `Account` or `AccountInfo` struct, which would carry the public key under `key` field already.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I store it as a variable though? I would want to use it to check whether the passed mint in the Context struct is in fact the constant I defined

Comment: I just remembered about this piece of code in the Anchor repo, https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/spl/src/mint.rs which I believe shows how we can use it as variables

Comment: Yep, that macro generates an `ID` in that module which you can later reference.

Comment: the `pubkey!()` wrapper for `declare_id!()` offers better self-documentation and should be preferred here.

Comment: @trent.sol, good one! I didn't know about that one. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to initialize constant Pubkeys in an organized way.

**Lib.rs**

```
// Program Id
declare_id!("e8zpvHybTbjMjoDR7CWjBUj1ttxQwRMUebhAf2z52ba");

mod pubkeys {
    use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

    // User Publickey
    pub mod user {
        use super::*;
        declare_id!("a8zpvHybTbjMjoDR7CWjBUj1ttxQwRMUebhAf2z5aaa");
    }

    // Vault Publickey
    pub mod vault {
        use super::*;
        declare_id!("b8zpvHybTbjMjoDR7CWjBUj1ttxQwRMUebhAf2z5bbb");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
use crate::*;

msg!("{}", ID)                   // prints Program Id
msg!("{}", pubkeys::user::ID);   // user User Address
msg!("{}", pubkeys::vault::ID);  // vault Vault Address
```